# When is git rm -f used?

Tags: git, git-rm

I am learning Git and am unable to understand under what condition the -f flag is used while issuing the "git rm" command. Please explain a scenario where rm -f would be required instead of rm only?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Explanation:

The `-f` is used to remove a file if the file is not up to date with your last checked out commit.  It is to prevent you from removing a file that you have made changes to, but have not yet checked them in.

### Example:

You check out commit *0a12d4* that contains the file *sample.txt*.  Before you change any files, you could remove the *sample.txt* with `git rm sample.txt`.  However, once you make a change to *sample.txt*, you would need to use `git rm -f sample.txt` to remove the file

Answer (score 4):

If you try to `git rm` a file that has unstaged changes, it fails if you don't provide the `-f` flag:

```
$ git rm a.txt
error: 'a.txt' has local modifications
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you edit a file, and then realize you want to delete it instead.

```
$ ls
func.c
$ vim func.c
...edit the file...
```

Now that I think about it, I actually want to delete it...

```
$ git rm func.c
error: 'func.c' has local modifications
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
$ git rm -f func.c
```